# Could not connect to server With PHPillow

Tags: php, apache, couchdb

When I try to connect to couchdb database using phpillow in Linux CentOs6, I get this error:
Could not connect to server at 127.0.0.1:5984: '13: Permission denied', but the same sample in windows work Fine!.
Any Idea?

Thanks in advance!

Gustavo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue!.

The issue was a infrastructure problem, with the Apache over permission folders of the CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably on the CouchDB side, since phpillow is forwarding a CouchDB error.

Are you sure CouchDB it's correctly installed / has the right permissions?

Are you able to access it directly?

Comment: Hi Alix!

Yes, I can access directly, using something like this http://127.0.0.1:5984/ and Couchdb response: {"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"91a57e50db70260d409c31e5669d5d68","version":"1.3.0","vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation","version":"1.3.0"}}, and I can use _utils without problem. I just check all ports and all looks fine.
It's very disconcerting!

Comment: @GustavoSalazar: No idea then, I hope someone else helps you out.